# Spring Batch FlowStep in Partitioner restart issue

Tags: spring-batch

Here is what I'm trying to achieve in a Spring Batch job:

- A partitioner launches a FlowStep
- The FlowStep consists of n step(s)
- In case of failure, I want a consistent restart of the inner steps

I encounter the following issue during a restart:
Suppose I have 2 partitions, for the sake of simplicity I have a syncTaskExecutor. The first partition (partition0) runs well, we run now the second partition (partition1).

The first problem is that the sub-steps of the FlowStep are detected as duplicates. This is because the names of the sub-steps are not suffixed with the partition index. But the steps run ultimately.

The consequence of this happens if one sub-step fails. In that case, during a restart, since all sub-steps of the partition0 execution exit successfuly, the remaining steps of partition1 won't be executed.

The main problem here is that the sub-steps of a partitioner are not indexed and therefor detected as equivalent but they are not.

Additionally I don't want to set the sub-steps as restartable because I just want the missing steps to be executed and not all of them.

Am I missing something at this point? Do you have an alternative for what I want to do?

I know I could also launch a real job from the partitioner (using a JobStep) but this is not as powerful as FlowStep because we are really limited by the parameters we can provide to a job (no existing ExecutionContext). The guy here had the same issue I guess (
[Spring batch Partitioning with multiple steps in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23357024/spring-batch-partitioning-with-multiple-steps-in-parallel))

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging in the Spring Batch arcanes, I think I can answer my own question and maybe help some other people.

The key here is to provide our own `StepHandler` instead of the default `SimpleStepHandler`. In this handler, we can use the provided `ExecutionContext` to look after a predefined key that will contain the current partition id. We just need to use this id to build a unique step name in the form `step.getName() + ":" + id`.

In order to insert this custom `StepHandler`, we override the default `FlowStep` implementation.

A complete example can be found here https://github.com/miremond/spring-boot-sample-batch.