# Spring batch nested job or steps and how to get access to parent execution context in child partitioner

Tags: java, spring, nested, jobs

I have several question all related to each other.

I have a job in spring batch with a partitioner. It basically loads a lot of ftp configurations.

For each configuration I want to download a filelist and in the next step download and upload one file at a time from the list.

I'm very new to spring and spring batch so I do not even know if this is possible or not? That is my first question.

The second question is: If I can nest jobs or flows like this. How to get access to parent executionContext in the child partitioner?

Below you can se an example a terrible one I know it is basically just an idea of what I want not even close to working.

```
    <job id="loadFromFtpJob" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
    <step id="partitionedLoadFtpConfigurations">
        <partition partitioner="loadFtpPartitioner">
            <handler grid-size="1" task-executor="taskExecutor" />
            <step>
                <flow parent="downloadListFromFTPFlow" />
            </step>
        </partition>
    </step>
</job>

<!-- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23357024/spring-batch-partitioning-with-multiple-steps-in-parallel -->
<flow id="downloadListFromFTPFlow" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
    <step id="partitionedLoadFtpFiles">
        <partition partitioner="LoadFtpFilesPartitioner">
            <handler grid-size="1" task-executor="taskExecutor2" />
            <step>
                <flow parent="downloadFtpListFlow" />
            </step>
        </partition>
    </step>
</flow>

<flow id="downloadFtpListFlow" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
    <step id="downloadFromFtp" next="uploadToFtp">
        <tasklet ref="downloadFromFtpTasklet" />
    </step>
    <step id="uploadToFtp" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
        <tasklet ref="uploadToFtpTasklet" />
    </step>
</flow>
```

Comment: Instead of nesting jobs, why don you use the same job class and different methods for achieving that?

Comment: I might be wrong but if I do that will i get automated logging and transaction handling explicitly for every file down and/or uploaded?
Logging I can always handle in other ways but transaction handling?

Comment: Yes, if the Transaction is the correct layer, in service, you may have each transaction for each action, as services should do that.

Comment: Could you specify what you mean by "Transaction is the correct layer"?

It sounds like I should rethink what I'm doing. But what I was aiming at in my question is it even close to possible to do or not?

You are talking about transactions in the right layer I',m not really sure what you mean could you give me a hint where to look into this further? Or tell me what pitfalls I should look out for?